# vue - changing localstate triggers vuex error

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Whenever i update local state, vuex throws error `[vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.` even though I am not even trying to change vuex store. What is the problem?

```
data: {
 selected: []
},
methods: {
 addItem(item){
  this.selected.push({
   name: item.name,
   count: item.count
  })
 },
 applySelected(){
  this.$store.dispatch('changeItems', this.selected)
 }
}
```

```
<button @click="item.count++"/>
<span>{{item.count}}</span>
<button @click="item.count--"/>
```

items are in loop but proper markup and surrounding code is unnecessary for that example.
Now when selected[] is empty, when i do addItem(item) it works fine. Then when i change count, it still works just fine. When i commit changed to the store, guess what - it still works fine. But when i try to change count after it was submitted to the store, even though i have 0 getters, not reading store at all, don't have any additional mutation/dispatch calls, whenever i try to change count of selected[] items, it throws vuex error. but why?

Comment: Can you show your action and mutation code here?

Answer (score 1):

it doesnt make any sense to change vuex state in component. its better to change it via a mutation.

but there is a way to solve this locally and you have to call a function that returns new object of items in vuex store. maybe like this:

```
computed: {
   selected() {
       return () => this.$store.state.selected
   }
}
```